# I am operating a DELL optiplex 210L with UBUNTU 22.04. A BROTHERS HL-L2320D is attached by USB cable. Want to make it my network printer

Tags: networking, server, printing, 22.04

My printer is attached to my desk computer running ubuntu 22.04.  Computer attached to router by cable.  Printer attached to computer by usb.  Windows 11 computer attached to same router by wi-fi. I want to make printer a network printer so I can prirnt from Windows computer.

Comment: Open Printer Settings, Additional Printer Settings. Right-click on your USB printer. Select SHARE.

Comment: this has already been tried.  It doesn't work.

Comment: Temporarily disable your firewall and see if it helps.